# need help errors and lots of missing packages ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, apt, software-center, package-management, system

i am running ubuntu 13.10 on an msi notebook, i am in no way computer literate and to try and fix one small problem i have unintentionally gotten in way over my head, created more problems and am in need of some serious help

first of all my original problem, i got internet set up in my new house and although it was showing connected i can only connect through smart phone tethering.
my top right hand menu icons are completely gone (time/date, rythym box, shutdown, setting, the cloud ect) 
i am getting constant error reports which through days of trying every sudo command and update i can i still cant get rid of.
my software centre, unity dash, software and updates and a few other smaller programs wont work 
when i try to redownload any of these nothing happens, using sudo commands to install just brings up package not found errors 
and somewhere along the line i have reverted my updates to look through old release packages and not the newer ones, i have no idea how to fix this. 
i lost my .deb installer and i cant get it back through the internet or terminal commands so none of my deb files will install

after days of trying else i thought maybe ut ubuntu 13.10 or xubuntu 13.10 onto a flashdrive and reboot it in the hope i get my packages and missing programs back, i managed to torrent download ubuntu 13.10 and then realised i dont have the original startup usb creator either, i have tried and failed to download multiple different ones but due to the missing deb. installer and software centre i cant do this either. im not sure what information is needed so please get back to me and ill provide as much as i can

i am at a complete loss of what to do so any help would be highly highly appreciated, if this is fixable at all.

thanks for your time

Comment: It's possible, but likely a lot more work than it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you backup all your data from /home and reinstall or better yet install a fresh copy of 14.04 LTS.

13.10 will be EOL (out of support) July 2014. Considering the age of this question, we could still not have a working system under 13.10 for you by then. 14.04 is a Long Term Support release and will be supported until April 2019.

By installing 14.04 fresh you'll have a working system + the data you backed up + the knowledge that you can come here for help before things get out of hand.